# Making video inside a modal responsive - Bootstrap 4

Tags: video, iframe, modal-dialog, bootstrap-4, responsive

So I am playing a video from youtube (inside a modal, trigged by a button) using Bootstrap 4.

The problem is: if I re-size the webpage's window, the modal is repsonsive but the video playing inside of it, is not.

I tried fixing this with jQuery or Media Queries but didn't manage to make it work properly.

Is there an efficient and simple way to do this?

Here is my code:

```
<!-- Video Play -->
  <section id="video-play">
    <div class="dark-overlay">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="container p-5">
            <a href="" class="video" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal" data-video="https://www.youtube.com/embed/id-video">
              <i class="fas fa-play fa-3x"></i>
            </a>
            <h1>See What We Do</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Video MODAL -->
  <div id="videoModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
            <span>&times;</span>
          </button>
          <iframe src="" frameborder="0" height="765" width="765" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Basically what I am trying to do is to make the attributes height and width of the iframe tag reflect the device's screen size (or we could say responsive).

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Thank you in advance for your time and help!

Marco

Comment: your markup doesn't give the button to trigger this, doesn't give any css. You need to give us relevant information to helping fix it. Also, you want to let us know what you have tried to do and hasn't worked. Post a working codepen or something.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see our [documentation on creating a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can get a better understanding of the problem you are facing and how to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using bootstrap, you might be able to do this by using the embed-responsive class, but it's hard to say without having a codepen to refer to.

Check out this link: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/embed/